# Unable to add users in AD using New-ADUser on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have been trying to bulk-load users into AD by using a CSV file in windows server 2012r2, but `New-ADUser` keeps throwing an error. I haven't used any attribute which isn't mentioned in `New-ADUser` yet it doesn't work.

The code is:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#set password
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "xyzzy" -AsPlainText -Force

#enter file path of csv file
$filepath = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter path"

$Users = Import-Csv $filepath

foreach ($User in $Users) {
    $fname = $User.firstname
    $lname = $User.lastname
    $empid = $User.empid
    $emailadd = $User.email
    $username = $User.username
    $ou = $User.ou
    $location = $User.loc
    $dept = $User.dept


New-ADUser -SamAccountName $username -Name $username -GivenName $fname -Surname $lname -UserPrincipalName "$fname@TEST.LCL" -Path $ou -AccountPassword $password -ChangePasswordAtLogon $True -EmailAddress $emailadd -Country $location -Department $dept -EmployeeID $empid

}
```

The error it keeps on throwing is:

```
New-ADUser : The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist
Parameter name: name
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\bulk.ps1:20 char:1
+ New-ADUser -SamAccountName $username -Name $username -GivenName $fname -Surname  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-ADUser], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
```

Comment: Your error message shows another line of code than you do in your example! Did you notice that? Take a really close look to the error message and maybe read it out loud for yourself!  ;-)  .. .regardless of that you might read about [Powershell splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6). That could make your code a little clearer and easier to read.

Comment: Your error does not match the code you claim to be running. Please create a [mcve] that exposes the behavior you're trying to troubleshoot and post *that* code along with the error message thrown by *that* code. With that said, the most likely explanation for the behavior you describe is a blank line somewhere in your CSV (probably at the end).

Comment: Apart from the points already made, that whole list of variables is completely unnecessary, you can just call the attributes directly in New-ADUser with this syntax "NewADUser -SamAccountName $User.username ..."

Comment: @Olaf am sorry for that, now i have corrected the error message.I have also tried powershell splatting and it still doesn't work

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers i have corrected the error message and no there are no empty lines or spaces in the csv

Comment: I see you are setting both `-SamAccountName` and `-Name` to have the same value of $username. Are you sure about this? [the docs]() say that `SamAccountName` has a maximum length of the description is 256 characters. To be compatible with older operating systems, create a SAM account name that is 20 characters or less. As for the `Name` : Be sure user names do not contain special characters or leading/ending spaces.